# How to give a Geometric shape to a DIV?

Tags: css

Is this possible: to create DIVs around of current DIV?

For example, some DIV lies in the center (big circle) and other DIVs are around it (stars), like on the picture. Does CSS can achieve such tasks?

[image: Example of positions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ofcourse go through this links.. [link1](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) and [link2](http://www.css3shapes.com).

and then set the `div`'s by giving [postioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) :) cheers.

**Update**: (*added only chrome vendor prefix*)

### HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="star topMid"></div>
    <div class="star top left"></div>
    <div class="star top right"></div>
    <div class="star midLeft"></div>
    <div class="star midRight"></div>
    <div class="star bottom left"></div>
    <div class="star bottom right"></div>
    <div class="star bottomMid"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.parent {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.parent:after {
    content:"";
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 55px;
    left: 55px;
    right: 55px;
    bottom: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.star {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}
.star:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    top: 7px;
    left: -20px;
}
.top {
    top: 12.5%;
}
.left {
    left: 12.5%;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 20%;
}
.right {
    right: 12.5%;
}
.topMid {
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
.bottomMid {
    bottom: 25px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
.midLeft {
    top:50%;
    left:5px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
.midRight {
    top:50%;
    right:5px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/DbpSu/)

Comment: Hi, @Mr_Green  can i also align a text in that div, like this https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ5z8OYxnypDr09mmfFMunJj31x_XtfG3MFj0vlAa_ceoCnts0OfQ

Comment: @kulkata do you mean like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/cSu2j/) ?

Comment: Nearly, not exactly. I realized i want too much from css :/ Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kulkata yeah I get it.. you don't want the text to be hidden... I am sure that this is not possible using css2 but may be possible with css3. post a new question with clear explanation you may get your answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve such a layout, you can use [absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Answer (score 1):

Guys already said correct answer with absolute positioning. But here is the tip I would suggest:

```
    <div class="bigDiv">
         <div class="smallDive">

         </div>
          <div class="smallDive">

         </div>
         <div class="smallDive">

         </div>
         //...
    </div>

    .bigDive{
       position:relative;
       //...
     }
     .smallDiv{
       position:absolute;
       //...
     }
```

So in that case inner smallDive's position will be calculated based on big dives positon, NOT according to display's corners.